# No displaying results when running remotely using pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, remote-server, remote-development

When I run a python script using remote development in Pycharm Pro, the run tool window doesn't display results while the script is actually running.
[My Run Configurations can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN8jo.png)

what could be the reasons?

I tried to run the command below in the terminal, the code starts to run and it gives results in the terminal:

```
/root/miniconda3/bin/python /root/a/x.py
```

SO the code and the interpreter is fine, I assume.